# How to resolve 'com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found' error in JBoss?

Tags: java-8, jboss

I am getting this error:*Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found* in jboss Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.1.5.GA when trying to call the below in my method.

```
    import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to overcome it, and please note that the method works fine when running as standalone, not in jboss.

I added several jars in my module.xml, but none of them did the trick.

```
    **<resource-root path="MySoapWebService.jar"/>
**
    <resource-root path="jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-text-1.10.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-io-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="json.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="saaj-impl-1.5.1.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="commons-io-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="httpclient-4.5.13.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="httpmime-4.3.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-annotations-2.8.7.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-core-2.8.7.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jersey-client-1.17.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jersey-core-1.17.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="mail-1.4.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="saaj-impl-1.3.16-jbossorg-1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activation-1.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="mimepull-1.9.7.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="stax-api-1.0-2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="stax-ex-2.1.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="angus-activation-2.0.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="saaj-api-1.3.5.jar"/>



    </resources>

    <dependencies>

    <module name ="javax.api"/>
    <module name ="javaee.api"/>
 



    </dependencies>

    </module>
```

Comment: are you using pom.xml? or you have defined all dependencyin module.xml

Comment: Are you trying to override the `javax.xml.soap.api` module?

Comment: @Abhishek I am not using pom.xml

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am not, but that error just pops up, when writing the above line. I am trying to create a soap message with attachment, to give you an overview of my functionality. When testing this from a standalone point of view it works fine, but when doing it from jboss I get this error.

Comment: You’re including a different SOAP library which may attempt to override the `javax.xml.soap.api` module. You should depend on that module rather than replace it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I have added explicitly <module name ="javax.xml.soap.api"/> under dependencies and removed <resource-root path="jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.1.jar"/>, but now I get an error with the actual SOAP call,                       SOAPMessage response = connection.call(soapMessage, new URL(endpointUrl));, so it seems it doesn't work, I am getting this: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: JBWS024004: SOAP message could not be sent
 at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:130) Any other thoughts?

Comment: Without the full stack trace it's hard to tell what it could be.